# MimePartBody.getDisposition() returning null for inline parts

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime

So I am trying to make a dragNdrop application which takes .eml files and saves the various bits.
The attachement part has not given me any issues but the message body and images contained are.
In my code I am using the javax.mail library.
Using the method

```
MimeBodyPart.getDisposition()
```

It correctly gives back 'attachment' when I print out the string but for the inline part it gives back 'null' and clumps together the images and body.
In the .eml file(generated with lotus notes) you can clearly see the Content-Disposition/ID/Type/Transfer-encoding... of each part.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here is the loop that deals with this:

```
for (File file: files) {
    System.out.println(file.getPath());
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.host", "smtp.dummydomain.com");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    try {
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
            System.out.println(part.getDisposition());
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                System.out.println("part " + i);
                part.saveFile("C:/" + part.getFileName());
            }

        }

    } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

The file object is correctly initialized since I get the pathname back and also the attachment saved.

Any help would be most appreciated.

The following is a slightly modified example of en .eml file. The inline image and the attachement where shortened to only a few lines to enable me to post it here:

```
From: someone@domain.com
X-Notes-Item: Mon, 8 May 2017 10:59:55 +0200;
 type=400; name=OriginalModTime
X-Notes-Item: Memo;
 name=Form
X-Notes-Item: stdNotesLtr25;
 name=Logo
X-Notes-Item: ;
 name=dLogo
X-Notes-Item: True;
 name=useApplet
X-Notes-Item: 1;
 name=DefaultMailSaveOptions
X-Notes-Item: 1;
 name=ExpandPersonalGroups
X-Notes-Item: ;
 name=tmpImp
X-Notes-Item: ;
 name=Sign
X-Notes-Item: Stack Overflow saved my life.;
 flags=6; name=$Abstract
X-Notes-Item: Vertraulich;
 name=ConfidentialString
X-Notes-Item: ;
 name=Classification
Subject: Example email
X-KeepSent: 2C23BC4F:883C3D54-C125811A:0030D552;
 type=4; name=$KeepSent
To: NJun@domain.com
X-Notes-Item: ;
 flags=45; name=InetCopyTo
X-Notes-Item: 1;
 name=$StorageTo
X-Mailer: IBM Notes Release 9.0.1FP7 August 18, 2016
Message-ID: <OF2C23BC4F.883C3D54-ONC125811A.0030D552-C125811A.00316E89@LocalDomain>
Sender: NJun@domain.com
Date: Mon, 8 May 2017 10:59:55 +0200
X-Notes-Item: 0;
 name=Encrypt
X-Notes-Item: CN=N Jun/OU=GU/OU=AT/O=domain;
 type=501; flags=44; name=$UpdatedBy
X-Notes-Item: 2C23BC4F:883C3D54-C125811A:0030D552;
 type=4; name=$Orig
X-Notes-Item: ;
 type=501; name=Categories
X-Notes-Item: ;
 type=401; name=$Revisions
X-Notes-Item: CN=S-NOTESGU001/OU=AT/O=domain;
 type=501; flags=0; name=RouteServers
X-Notes-Item: 08-May-2017 10:59:55 CEDT/08-May-2017 10:59:55 CEDT;
 type=401; flags=0; name=RouteTimes
X-Notes-Item: Mon, 8 May 2017 10:59:55 +0200;
 type=400; name=DeliveredDate
X-Notes-Item: 2C23BC4F:883C3D54-C125811A:0030D552;
 type=4; name=$TUA
X-Notes-Item: 1;
 name=$NoteHasNativeMIME
X-Notes-Item: CN=N Jun/OU=GU/OU=AT/O=domain@domain;
 name=OriginalTo
X-Notes-Item: CN=N Jun/OU=GU/OU=AT/O=domain;
 name=OriginalFrom
X-Notes-Item: CN=someone/O=domain;
 name=OriginalPrincipal
X-MIMETrack: Serialize by notes2.exe on N Jun/GU/AT/domain(Release 9.0.1FP7|August
 18, 2016) at 08.05.2017 11:40:46
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed; 
    Boundary="0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2"

--0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2
Content-type: multipart/related; 
    Boundary="1__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2"

--1__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2
Content-type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>
<table id="memoReadTable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr valign="top"><td width="0%"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""></td><td width="100%"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td><td width="1%"><img width="53" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="1%"><img width="90" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td><td width="100%"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td><td width="1%"><img width="53" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td></tr>

<tr valign="top"><td width="1%"><img width="102" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>

<ul style="padding-left: 4pt"><font size="1" color="#929292" face="sans-serif">An:</font></ul>
</td><td width="100%" valign="middle"><img width="1" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
<font size="1" face="sans-serif">NJun@domain.com</font></td><td width="1%"><img width="53" height="1" src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" alt=""><br>
</td></tr>
</table>
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">Stack Overflow saved my life.</font><br>
<br>
<img src="cid:0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df93869091@local" width="1030" height="282"><br>
<i>(Siehe angeh&#228;ngte Datei: DT between trees.jpg)</i></body></html>
--1__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2
Content-type: image/gif; 
    name="02629422.gif"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="02629422.gif"
Content-ID: <0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df93869091@local>
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

R0lGODlhBgQaAecAAP///xgQGCAYIPDw8Ojo6CggKDAoMPj48JCQkEA4QGBYYODg4NjY2PD4+Gho
aNDQ0CAQGKCgoBgQIMjIyDgwOMDAwKioqLi4uBgQKCAYKLCwsOjw+Pj46FBIUOj4+BgQMCgQGCgY

...........Shortened............

QAgMLxngkLgwYcIFO1OWQHbZObbs2bQpHligJsKPEhEuMJhaO7jw4cSLGz8+2EkYLTIC9QACaUoW
FRACGDFAgQ9S5Ny7e/8OPrz48eTLkz8wYADwh+nTrzcPP778+fTr27+PP7/+/fz7+/8PYIACDkhg
gQYeiGCCCi4SyGCDDj4IYYQSTkhhhRZeOFJAADs=


--1__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2--


--0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2
Content-type: image/jpeg; 
    name="DT between trees.jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DT between trees.jpg"
Content-ID: <C3__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df93869091@local>
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

/9j/4V/+RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAA4BAgAgAAAA8BUAAA8BAgAYAAAAEBYAABABAgARAAAAKBYA
ABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAApBAAABsBBQABAAAArBAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAgAAAA

.................Shortened...............................................

M0+RCg4q1qzknLUqyTbFOT0rK87zXOPWk11Mmf/V6rB29earngtnmvwGL1P02EtTOuJGY4FRAFQM
810dDrU1YXzATjNaFqFHJqXsS5XNaFl2jnipJmDIdtYqN2YSZ//W3pgd1Y13aPK5Jr8Op6I/SpS6
C29kUIxWtaQBW9TUVJ3MXM3rYKAPpUz4IxXI1qZt3ZCVXn1qtMUweBWdtTRH/9k=

--0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2--
```

Comment: I need more details.  Can you post an example.eml file that shows the problem?  Also, note that not every possible message will be a simple multipart message with attachments; there any many other message structures that can occur.  Unless you know that all the messages you're processing will use exactly and only this format, your program will need to handle the other cases as well.  See the [JavaMail msgshow.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java).

Comment: Hello Bill. Thank you for your reply. 
In the edit is an example. Normally the .eml files should all be the same as they will be generated by the same program (Lotus Notes).

Answer (score 0):

Your example .eml file shows a multipart/related nested inside the outer multipart/mixed.  The [msgshow.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) shows that the message has this structure:

```
This is the message envelope
---------------------------
FROM: someone@domain.com
REPLY TO: someone@domain.com
TO: NJun@domain.com
SUBJECT: Example email
SendDate: Mon May 08 01:59:55 PDT 2017
FLAGS: 
X-Mailer: IBM Notes Release 9.0.1FP7 August 18, 2016
CONTENT-TYPE: multipart/mixed; 
        boundary="0__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2"
This is a Multipart
---------------------------
  CONTENT-TYPE: multipart/related; 
        boundary="1__=4EBB0B89DFA353C28f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0B89DFA353C2"
  This is a Multipart
  ---------------------------
    CONTENT-TYPE: text/html; charset=US-ASCII
    ---------------------------
    CONTENT-TYPE: image/gif; name=02629422.gif
    FILENAME: 02629422.gif
    ---------------------------
  CONTENT-TYPE: image/jpeg; name="DT between trees.jpg"
  FILENAME: DT between trees.jpg
  ---------------------------
```

Your sample code is only processing the outer multipart/mixed.  The outer multipart/mixed also includes an image/jpeg attachment, which your code should find.  The inner multipart/related includes an image/gif inline component, which your code will never see.

I can't see any reason your code should get null for the disposition of the image/jpeg part.  Are you using IMAP to access the message?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: Oh, wow. This is so helpful. I will take a look at the JavaMail debug (I hadn't set it to true) and let you know what I find. I am not using IMAP though.

Comment: If you're just reading the message from a file, look at the msgshow.java program.

Comment: I have finally been able to work on the code again.
I can't get the msgshow. java to work. I don't know how to input the :eml file.
I tried something else. Since one of the Bodyparts from the Multipart object is a Multipart I want to cast the BodyPart as a Multipart. That way I can loop though the BodyParts of the multipart/related. It doesn't work of course. In the msgshow.java it seems to work though.
I have set the JavaMail debug to true but it gives no errors.
I have done alot of looking around on multipart/related and nobody seems to have a comprehensive response.